# Why is my program printing zeros instead of -1

Tags: c

I'm supposed to make a searching program where I have to input data of n customers where each data contains ID, name, age, and balance of each customer.

Then the user is asked to input m queries. For each query, given a variable x to search in the first array whether customer whose ID is x exists. If it exists, the program outputs the customer's data, if it doesn't, the program outputs "-1".

Here for each query in which the ID exists, I've successfully printed the customer's data by first storing them to new arrays, but for query of x that doesn't exist my code is printing zeros instead of -1.

I suppose the problem is somewhere around the last and second last for loops of my code or maybe I'm initializing the count variable wrong but I still can't figure out what I'm supposed to fix.

Here's a sample input

```
    5
    ANGE,Andrew Garfield,18,110933.25
    HAIS,Spectra Vgeist,18,25000.00
    NERA,Frankie,16,999999999.99
    TION,Dorothy White,22,0.00
    VVVV,Michael J,17,100000.00
    3
    NERA
    JOLY
    VVVV
```

what the output's supposed to look like

```
        Frankie 16 999999999.99
        -1
        Michael J 17 100000.00
```

But instead, this is what my program prints out

```
        Frankie 16 999999999.99
         0 0.00
        Michael J 17 100000.00
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Customer{
    char ID[100];
    char name[100];
    int age;
    double balance;
}N[1000];

int main(){
    int n,i,x,j,b[100],count[100];
    char m[100][100];
    char a[100][100];
    double c[100];
    
    scanf("%d",&n);
    getchar();
    
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf(" %[^,],%[^,],%d,%lf",N[i].ID,N[i].name,&N[i].age,&N[i].balance);
        getchar();
    }
    scanf("%d",&x);
    for(i=0; i<x; i++){
        scanf("%s",m[i]);
        getchar();
        
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<x; j++){
            if(strcmp(m[j],N[i].ID) == 0){
                strcpy(a[j],N[i].name);
                b[j] = N[i].age;
                c[j] = N[i].balance;
                count[j] = 0;
            }   
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<x; i++){
        if(count[i] == 0){
            printf("%s %d %.2lf\n",a[i],b[i],c[i]);
        }
        else{
            printf("-1\n");
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: More descriptive variable names would be a good start.

Comment: I don't see any place in your code where elements of the `count` array are set to anything besides 0, so it stands to reason that when the final loop runs, they all contain 0 and you never enter the `-1` case.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `count`, however you do not initialize its values. Most likely it grabs a memory block filled with zeros, which means your comparison `count[i] == 0` will always be true, thus not print `-1`. To fix this I would recommend initializing the array `count` with the value `1`. By doing this, the equality above will only be true if `count[j]` is explicitly set to `0`. To initialize the array, do the following immediately after declaring the array:

```c
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   count[i] = 1
}
```

Personally, I would initialize the `count` array with zero and attribute 1 to `count[j]` when necessary, as I think it makes more sense when having a variable called `count`. Either way, but solutions work, if you decide do change it, please consider you'll also have to change the equality in the if clause.

Comment: I didn't realize I needed to initialize the array first before setting the value to zero. Thanks!!

Comment: @rrrr What value did you expect to read from `count[i]` in `count[i] == 0`?